# java: How Not to save values from the code when looping back again?

Tags: java

How do I not store values from the program when it loops back again.  For example, if I plan to enter two families, first I will ask for the details of the first family and display their names, and then I want to use the same variables to collect the next family and display their names without having stored information from the previous family.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String ans; 
    String res;
    double cont;
    int cot;
    String name;
    String order = "";

    do {

    ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What is the name of the "
            + "family?" );

    res = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many member in the " + ans +
            " family?");

    cot = Integer.parseInt(res); // Converts res String to a number 

     for (int count = 1; count < cot; count ++)  {

        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " Enter first name: " + count);
        order += name + " " + ans + "\n";
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Members of the " + ans
            + " Family" + "\n" + order);

    cont = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to add another "
            + "family", "Membership", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    }while (cont == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

     if (cont == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Come Back Again");

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Your code looks like it's doing what you describe. If there is a problem you should be more explicit and state what it is.

Comment: Why `ans`, `res`, `cot`? What do these mean? Please use descriptive variable names: `familyName`, `familyMembers`...

Comment: It sounds like the first step is to make a `class Family`. Then, if you want a new family each loop, simply do `Family f = new Family();`.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils This looks like an assignment and he maybe didn't get into OOP yet.

Comment: Then they're being setup to fail if they're using GUI components and have yet to touch OOP @m0skit0; but, yes, possible.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils They're only using static methods ;) But I digress, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, the variable names I created don't really mean anything. I'll for sure fix them. This is an assignment I am doing for a course I have. I'm not allowed to create a class. Every time it loops back again the names of the previous family is displayed I want to get rid of that,  but I don't know how.

Comment: Look at the code and what it does. There's a particular reason why you still have the previous values when the loop *begins*. If you wanted to set the variables to some default values each time the loop ***begins***, where would you need to put that code?

Comment: Nowhere. This is the instruction; if the user clicks 'Yes', then repeat the instructions starting with the name of the family.
You do not have to save the data from the last family.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your order variable is a String that you are adding the names to.  Just reset it at the beginning of the loop:

```
...
do {
order = "";
...
```